# Check file by format and not by extension

Tags: android, file, android-studio, pdf, kotlin

In my application I have an option to attach pdf, png files etc. It can happen that a person changes the extension to a malicious file and puts .pdf or .png.

How can I verify that a file is a pdf or png by format and not by file extension which is how I am doing it now?

i am doing this:

```
if(file.endsWith("pdf")){
 //is okey
}else{
 //this is not a pdf file
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have checked if a file is an Image by running the following:

```
final Drawable drawable = BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(realFileName);
if (drawable != null) {
    // Is an Image
}
```

If you can use API 26+ you can make use of `Files.probeContentType(file.toPath())`. This will provide the MimeType of the file provided.

Lastly, you could use Apache Tika to inspect the first few bytes of the file. I've not done this before but it would look something like:

apps build.gradle

```
implementation group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers', version: '1.22'
```

Then use where needed:

```
Tika tika = new Tika();
try {
    Log.d(TAG, tika.detect(file));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

https://tika.apache.org/1.22/index.html

Comment: Please note that this will not protect you or your users from Malware! A proper virus scanner should be used (https://scanii.com/ for a SaaS version) to try and weed out MalWare (it can hide quite well within PNG and PDF Files).